# Removing a vector pointer object element in a map

Tags: c++

I have a map which contains a string and a vector to a pointer object. When I try to delete an object in the vector it seems to work but when I list out all of the vector objects in another function the program crashes/aborts when it hits the deleted objects location. I'm believe I've messed up deleting the objects and pointers are pointing to NULL which is why this is happening but I have really no idea at this point.

```
//map is: map<string, vector<baseObject *>>

vector<Message*>::iterator v_itr;
vector<baseObject*> & vec = itr->second;
    for (v_itr = vec.begin(); v_itr != vec.end(); v_itr++){

    firstDerivedObj * p_first = dynamic_cast<TextMessage*>(*v_itr);
    secondDerivedObj * p_second = dynamic_cast<VoiceMessage*>(*v_itr);

    if (p_first){
        delete p_first;
    }
    if (p_second){ delete p_second; }
}
```

The code looks like it deletes without error but when I run another function to display all of the vectors in the map it program crashes.

Comment: Read about [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). Especially pay close attention to what it returns. Use of it will require some refactoring of your loop.

Comment: `delete` only deletes the memory the pointer points to.  It does nothing to the vector.

Comment: and don't store raw pointers in vectors other than for very transient operations.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: Also, having to use `dynamic_cast` to do runtime type-checking is usually a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Puzzled as to why the `dynamic_cast ` is required at all if you're going to `delete`. Are you missing a `virtual` destructor or am I missing something?

Comment: There are multiple derived classes from the base class and I wanted to check which polymorphic function to use later on in the code. I am not a good programmer so this might be me badly designing the objects because someone else mentioned I didn't need to use dynamic cast but I don't see how I can tell which polymorphic function is returned other than dynamic cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that after you delete the objects from the memory pointed to by a specific vector element, that element is still pointing to that memory location, which is causing your error.  I would suggest you need to erase that location from the vector as well.  Something like this should work:

```
vector<Message*>::iterator v_itr;
vector<baseObject*> & vec = itr->second;
for (v_itr = vec.begin(); v_itr != vec.end(); v_itr++){    
     firstDerivedObj * p_first = dynamic_cast<TextMessage*>(*v_itr);
     secondDerivedObj * p_second = dynamic_cast<VoiceMessage*>(*v_itr);
     if(p_first || p_second){
         if (p_first){
             delete p_first;
         }
         if (p_second){ 
             delete p_second; 
         }
         vec.erase(v_itr);
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much it works! Super annoyed about it through because I had that erase statement there just not the break. Without the break the function aborts/crashes. Why is the break necessary? I don't use it in other if statements and they end without error.

Comment: to short cut the loop. Erase changes the iterator to the next element and the loop gets screwed up.